# backup exec 2012: how know a specific tape content

Tags: windows-server-2003, backupexec

how can I know the content of a specific tape ?
I backed up my exchange 2007 mailboxes on a monthly mediaset, now I want export the media but I don't know which media I have to export.

Comment: Isn't that something you can do with the built in reporting services of Backup Exec?

Comment: A. Look at the job history for the job. It will list the media used by the job. - B. Look at the restore selections for the server/date in question. It will show the media that the restore job would restore from.

Comment: No, there is not any report that show the specific tape content.

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite some time since I used Backup Exec but hopefully this will help.

You should be able to find this information by selecting data to restore (you don't need to actually perform the restore). When you are setting up a restore job, find the data you are looking for (your exchange 2007 mailboxes). You'll have the option to either View by Resource or View by Media (different tabs). You'll want to view by media.

The View by Media tab displays nodes that represent the media that contain backup sets. Each node displays the media label for the media on which the backup set is contained.

Image Taken from Symantec:

[image: Image taken from Symantec:]

If a backup set spans multiple pieces of media, the node for that backup set displays the media labels for all of those pieces of media. Beneath that node, the backup sets displays.

To expand the view for a resource or piece of media, click the adjacent box that contains the plus sign (+). To collapse the view, click the minus sign (-).

When the view is expanded, backup sets contained on the resource or media are displayed. You can expand the backup set to view the data included in the backup. The data that has been backed up from the resource appears in the right pane of the Restore Job Properties - Selections dialog box. Remember that only media cataloged or backed up at this server are displayed in the views. If you want to restore data backed up at another installation of Backup Exec, you must catalog the media first.

You can traverse file levels from either side of the window by clicking folders and subfolders as they appear

Hopefully this will help you track down which media your backups are stored to.

Additionally, if you just want to search a specific tape it needs to be in the inventory and cataloged.

To Inventory a Tape/Robotic Library:

1. Insert the tape.
2. Click the Devices tab.
3. Select the correct tape drive/robotic library slot.
4. Right-click on the tape drive/robotic library slot and select Inventory (Figure 1).

[image: Image taken from Symantec]

The inventory will complete and should display the correct tape name.

What is a Catalog? 
When cataloging a tape, Backup Exec reads the header information from the tape and stores it in a file on the hard drive.

The information contained in the catalog includes, but is not limited to:

• Tape number/label/name (something to identify that tape from all others)

• Date and time of the backup

• Type of backup

• What directories/files were backed up

To Catalog a tape:

1. Click on the tape drive/robotic library
2. Select the tape from the right pane
3. Right-click the tape and select Catalog (Figure 3)

[image: Image from Symantec]

This will add the directory structure of the data on the tape to the restore tree. An inventory and catalog must be performed on all tapes to be included in a search.

Comment: I am sorry, but backup exec 2012 is pretty different.